# Store response type to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying yo gave the download results to a dataframe download portion works but at the end the dataframe is blank

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

url = 'https://www.cms.gov/files/zip/monthly-contract-summary-report-april-2020.zip'
FolderYear = '2020'
FolderName = 'ContractSummary'
FileName = 'monthly-contract-summary.zip'
FileDirectory = rootpath+FolderYear+"/"+FolderName+"/"
FullWritePath = rootpath+FolderYear+"/"+FolderName+"/"+FileName
if not os.path.exists(FileDirectory):
    os.makedirs(FileDirectory)

r = requests.get(url)

with open(FullWritePath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# Retrieve HTTP meta-data
print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.encoding)

df['Status'] = r.status_code
df['headers'] = r.status_code
df['FileName'] = FileName
df['FullWritePath'] = FullWritePath
df['ZipFileDowlondLink'] = url
```

Comment: There are many things which could go wrong, have you done any debugging? As an aside, you also seem to be mixing multiple naming conventions, which is confusing.

Comment: Sorry about names the only name I see different is the df['ZipFileDowlondLink'] = url

Comment: No error the print out does give me this

Comment: Beginning file download with requests
200
application/zip
None

Comment: _Sorry about names the only name I see different is the df['ZipFileDowlondLink'] = url_ `df`, `url`, `r` versus `FolderYear`, `FolderName`, `FileName`, etc.

Comment: _No error the print out does give me this_ Alright, but your post says that the dataframe is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead of your last few lines:

```
rows = []    
columns = ['Status', 'headers', 'FileName', 'FullWritePath', 'ZipFileDowlondLink']
rows.append([r.status_code, r.status_code, FileName, FullWritePath, url])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

print(df)

Status  headers                      FileName                                      FullWritePath                                 ZipFileDowlondLink
0     200      200  monthly-contract-summary.zip  .2020/ContractSummary/monthly-contract-summary...  https://www.cms.gov/files/zip/monthly-contract...
```